# Webview block ads InputStream from url not working

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, android-webview, inputstream

i changed this row with that :
"InputStream fis2 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.adblockserverlist);" original code
InputStream input = new URL("https://aaaaaa/blocked.txt").openStream(); changed code

i wanna read adblock txt list from url, not raw

Code Here:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            ByteArrayInputStream EMPTY = new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes());
            String kk5 = String.valueOf(adservers);
            if (kk5.contains(":::::"+request.getUrl().getHost())) {
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "utf-8", EMPTY);
            }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
    }
```

```
private void adservers(){
        String strLine2="";
        adservers = new StringBuilder();

        InputStream fis2 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.adblockserverlist);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));
        if(fis2 != null) {
            try {
                while ((strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                    adservers.append(strLine2);
                    adservers.append("\n");

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried to read txt from url but app crashed